# Unset deep session variable dynamic

Tags: php, session

My session class set a session dynamic deep:

simplified:

```
$keys = "test.deep.more";
$keys = explode(".", $keys);
$current = &$_SESSION;
foreach($keys as $key) {
  $current = &$current[$key];
}
```

Output is:

```
Array
(
  [test] => Array
    (
        [deep] => Array
            (
                [more] => 
            )

    )

)
```

But, how can I unset a variable?

```
unset($current)
```

does not work. `$current` is currently `null`, because `more` has no value.

Anyone a idea?

**EDIT:**

To be more clear: I need a way to unset a dynamic deep session array. My try:

```
$session = &$_SESSION;

foreach($keys as $key) {
  $session = &$session[$key];
}

unset($session);
```

Or does a `unset()` for a reference not work?

**EDIT2:**

Anyone a idea how i can dynamic create a function that unset a deep session? Without typing

```
 unset($_SESSION['test']['deep']['more'])
```

Comment: It does unset it if the value is `NULL`. https://eval.in/198093

Comment: Where about are you using `unset` in your code? You've to actually unset `$_SESSION['test']['deep']['more']`. At the moment, it looks like you're unsetting `$_SESSION['more']`.

Comment: I have updated my question a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot unset the referenced variable.

As per [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php)

> When you unset the reference, you just break the binding between variable name and variable content. This does not mean that variable content will be destroyed

#### For example;

```
<?php

$a = 1;
$b =& $a; //Assign $a to $b by reference
unset($b); //Unset $b (hoping to unset $a)

var_dump($a); //This prints
var_dump($b); //$b doesn't exist

?>
```

https://eval.in/198105

#### To accomplish your task

```
unsetDeep($_SESSION, 'more');
function unsetDeep(&$array, $findKey) {
  foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
    if (is_array($value) AND $key != $findKey) {
      unsetDeep($value, $findKey);
    } else {
      if ($key == $findKey){
        unset($array[$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: argh..ok thank you! Anyone a idea how i can dynamic create a function that unset a deep session? Without typing $_SESSION['test']['deep']['more']?

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: @trollz Try the solution I've just put into my answer :)

Comment: oh..my..god..thats really awesome man!! it works!! thank you soooo much!!

Comment: I sat three full days on this problem and was totally frustrated ... you are my lifesaver!